# How to find the outer contour of a floorplan in python

Tags: python, opencv

I have a floorplan in the format of jpeg and I would like to find the outer contour of the floorplan (as indicated in the blue line below). So that given any pixel, I can identify whether that point is inside or outside the building.

[image]

By applying some blurring and using the basic contour function from cv2,

```
floorplan = cv2.imread("Edited_floorplan_v2.jpeg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(floorplan, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
edges = cv2.Canny(blur, 50, 150)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

I can extract the contours like shown below.

[image]

Then I tried the following code

```
largest_contour_area = 0
for contour in contours:
    if (cv2.contourArea(contour)) > largest_contour_area:
        largest_contour_area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        largest_contour = contour
```

However the result was not satisfactory.

[image]

Is there something I can do so that I can only keep the largest outer contours? Thanks.

Comment: (After binalization,) Is it not possible to apply `floodFill` to the outside part?

Comment: @fana Actually after a bit of research myself, floodfill does seem promising for my problem. I will test it out. Thanks for the suggestion fana.

Comment: this isn't a convex hull anymore, this requires alpha shapes... or you could hope to find the contour that matches the outer contour of the floorplan. -- don't bother with floodfill and similar stuff. that's not getting you anywhere. you merely had to invert the picture and apply `findContours()` and find the largest one. floodfill is a red herring. -- ***please provide*** a clean source image so people can work with it and give you proper answers.

Comment: I can't understand meaning of "red herring".

What is enough is depend on what is really wanted.
When "outside mask" created with simple floodfill only is enough to some use case, no other way is needed.
Of course, if some requirement such as "pixels belonging to walls must be excluded" is existing, some other way will be needed.

Comment: So I think it is more useful to point out the problem you thinking clearly than to deny my simplest idea with only such negative words.

Comment: @GengWang in those pictures, the lines have gaps. this looks like the image was downsized, but with nearest neighbor sampling. these pictures, aside from not being source data (got stuff drawn over them) would need fixing up with erosion/dilation before they're suitable for _any_ further processing, be it findContours, connected components labeling, or floodfill.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Yes findContours failed mostly likely due to what you mentioned there (image downsized, lines have gaps etc.). Unfortunately I don't have the source floorplan and what I had is a scanned and photoshopped version of it. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: provide what you have. I said this can be fixed up and it can. from investigation I noticed that the black isn't really black either, and it's got a slight hue to it. there is a lot going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lesson learned: don't rush to post questions and do more research.

After a bit of research (also thanks @fana for pointing out), floodFill solves this problem like a charm. If your outer contour is enclosed, then all you need to do is to manually pick a few points in those open spaces and floodFill it.

```
seed_point1 = (120, 120)
seed_point2 = (90, 500)
seed_point3 = (800, 50)
seed_point4 = (2200, 100)

cv2.floodFill(blur, None, seed_point1, 0, loDiff=10, upDiff=10)
cv2.floodFill(blur, None, seed_point2, 0, loDiff=10, upDiff=10)
cv2.floodFill(blur, None, seed_point3, 0, loDiff=10, upDiff=10)
cv2.floodFill(blur, None, seed_point4, 0, loDiff=10, upDiff=10)
```

This is the result.
[image]

Comment: It's generally easier to pick a point *outside* the contour and floodfill the surrounding area (in black in your example). If your objects touch the edges, you can add a 1px wide black border all the way around the edge. Then fill with black from your new (0,0) and the *"paint"* can flow all the way around the edges.